# How to write query to get result form multiple tables in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I am doing project in laravel. There are two tables "categories" and "subcategories". "subcategories" table have categoryid as a foreign key.
I want to fetch  categoryname from categories table and subcategoryid,subcategoryname from subcategories table where categoryid = $categoryid.

Here is something what I did. $cat contains many categoryid's but, from this I got only subcategories details,

```
foreach($cat as $categoryid){
        $subcategories[] = Subcategory::where('categoryid', '=', $categoryid)->get();
}
```

I am not getting how to do this,please help.

Comment: Have you defined relations between your Eloquent Models? Please follow this link and read about relations, you can get all the data you want with just 1 line http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#relationships

Comment: you should read before ask